# AngularJS - ngOptions expressions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to access a list of objects to use as ngOptions inside a Select element.  No matter what I try, I cannot get the list to populate the Select.  If I render the options expression in the page, the data displays fine and seems to have the correct structure.  So I know its not a typo or something in my expression.  I CAN access the data.  Eg:

```
{{ form_event.providers.search_terms[form_event.type.toLowerCase()] }}

[{"group": "program", "name": "title"},
 {"group": "program", "name": "aspect_ratio"},
 {"group": "episode", "name": "aspect_ratio"},
 {"group": "episode", "name": "house_id"}]
```

So, given the data structure, this is how I think it could be done in ng-options, but it doesn't work:

```
<select ng-options="term.name group by term.group for term in
    form_event.providers.search_terms[form_event.type.toLowerCase()]">
</select
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9B3zN/1/

Any clues would be great.

Comment: `event.providers` and `form_event.providers`?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you use `ng-options` do not forget to add `ng-model` attribute to `select` otherwise it would not work

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="term.name group by term.group for term in form_event.providers[form_event.type.toLowerCase()]">
    <option value="">-- choose --</option>
</select>
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9B3zN/2/