# tolowercase string Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Very simple issue I cant seem to resolve, my markup

```
<select class="testing" ng-model="Car_name"  ng-options="item in categories['Car_name']">
```

I'm trying to change 'Car_name' to be 'car_name' however the server populated the ng-model & categories[] entries, so I'm not sure how I can watch and convert to lowercase in my controller.

If I could do

```
{{Car_name|lowercase}}
```

would be the easiest, but not sure on the format.

Answer (score 10):

### Option 1

You can do it by using [angular.$filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter) option

Sample look like

```
<td ng-model={{ lowercase_expression | lowercase}}><td>

$filter('lowercase')()
```

More details Please see this [angular document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/lowercase)

---

### Option 2

Please see this below discussion

[AngularJS - ngOptions expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24796702/angularjs-ngoptions-expressions)

---

### Option 3

You need to manually add a loop for your *`array`*. And convert to the object values to lower case by using [`toLowerCase()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp) function , and finally push the object to new array.

---

Answer (score 8):

This is built into AngularJS and can be access via `angular.lowercase(string);` and then used in your Controller like:

```
$scope.makeLowerCase = function(string){
   return angular.lowercase(string);
};
```

Now use in your DOM like:

`{{Car_name|makeLowerCase}}`

Comment: any chance of a plunkr? as I can't seem to make it work with this?