# Angular - lowercase in attribute concat

Tags: angular

Hi I'm new to angular and I'm trying to create an attribute inside of a div tag. Which I can do successfully. However, if possible, I need to change my input to lowercase during the concatenation.

```
<!--"Fade" Slider-->
<div *ngIf="sliderTypes.fade"

     <!--Works but needs to be all lowercase-->
     [attr.data-t]="filter.text + '-button'"


    class="blahh"
    [ngClass]="getSliderCss()"
    (click)='toggleSlider()'>
        <div class="blahh-filter-text">{{filter.text}}</div>
</div>
```

The code above works and results in `data-t="Servops-button"`, but again, is needed to be lowercase.

I attempted to do the following (below), but it doesn't work and breaks the page. Would anyone know how to implement lowercase within this line or file?

```
<!--"Fade" Slider-->
    <div *ngIf="sliderTypes.fade"

         <!--Breaks page-->
         [attr.data-t]="{{filter.text | lowercase}} + '-button'"


        class="blahh"
        [ngClass]="getSliderCss()"
        (click)='toggleSlider()'>
            <div class="blahh-filter-text">{{filter.text}}</div>
    </div>
```

Desired output is `data-t="servops-button"` (lower case s, rather than upper)

Comment: It's `angular`, not `angularjs`.

Comment: What does it means 'breaks the page'? Can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: @LucaRegazzi Sorry, I’ll edit the question. Whenever I use pipes or the braces, the page doesn’t render. The only thing that loads is the base index file, but all of the other HTML files that populate the index won’t render if I use the 2nd code block

Comment: @estus The pipes haven’t worked. I tried this in the 2nd block of code.

Comment: Post the error that is written in the browser console (press F12)

Answer (score 0):

I have not experienced with angularJS 4 but I hope this may help you.

[tolowercase string Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31383047/tolowercase-string-angular)

I have used in angular 2

```
{{message | uppercase}}
{{message | lowercase}}
```

Comment: It can't help. Linking to another answer isn't the answer. And the answer refers to AngularJS (1), not Angular (4).

Comment: It won't work out of the box. It requires the module to be loaded, and the answer says nothing on that.